# Pass positional arguments to drush via drushrc.php?

Tags: drush

drush allows you to pass default arguments in a drushrc.php-file like:

```php
    $command_specific['command'] = array(
      'argument' => 'value',
      …
    );
```

This seems only to work for named options. Is there a way to also pass positional arguments via drushrc.php (like the installation-profile for drush site-install)?

I tried to use `$command_specific['site-install'][0] = 'profile';` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, there is no command-specific argument feature in Drush.  You can't even use a pre-command hook to fill in the arguments, as Drush will check for required arguments before calling any command hooks.

Another option would be to define a shell alias, and define your argument there:

```
$options['shell-aliases']['myis'] = 'site-install xyzzy';
```

Then you can use this as `drush myis [other options]`, and your profile name will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

This shell alias works for me. This means that you can define a shell alias that sets default parameters (and options if you want) for an existing command:

```
$options['shell-aliases']['site-install'] = '--yes site-install xyzzy';
```

Developers would simply need to run `drush site-install`.